# Complex COUTIF?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I would like to count the number of "N" in count H based on the following ranges (user input):

01/07/2017 - 02/07/2017; 
03/07/2017 - 09/07/2017; 
10/07/2017 - 16/07/2017;

I am thinking of using COUNIF(a range, "N"). But I don't know how to set the range so that it can look up the value in column B based on the above user input so that the formula can search the value in column B within the range and count the number of N in column H

Comment: Can you please upload a screenshot that matches your description? Or edit your description to match your screenshot? Also, where is the user input? Do you want to count "N" in column H? or "H" in column G?

Comment: edited. The user input is the date range. 01/07/2017 - 02/07/2017; 03/07/2017 - 09/07/2017; 10/07/2017 - 16/07/2017;

so that the formula can search the value in column B within the range and count the number of N in column H

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start date and end date of the time frame need to go in separate cells. If you put them all in one cell it makes the matter unnecessarily complicated.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$B$17>=StartDate),--($B$2:$B$17<=EndDate),--($H$2:$H$17="N"))
```

[image]

Or with CountifS()

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$17,">="&StartDate,$B$2:$B$17,"<="&EndDate,$H$2:$H$17,"N")
```